# Insuffcient permission of google signin id_token for GCP functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-signin, google-iam

Now I'm using google cloud functions under our company network policy(on GCP). The policy is to prevent from the external IP.

If I need to execute the function, I should get help from google scheduler or run my code on my local PC which SDK and auth login were installed on.

However, I want other users to use it on the web I'll develop.

So, I found a way by signing in Google end-user singin(?) as this [LINK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)
I was able to get the id_token.But when I sent
`curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME  -H "Authorization: bearer {ID_TOKEN_FROM_SIGNIN}"` on CLI, the result was

```
Your client does not have permission to the requested URL {MY-FUNCTIONS_URL}
```

However, when I tried it with `curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"`, the success result arrived.

The difference between two codes was that I used id_token from Google end-user singing or SDK configured the service account key.

Of course, I set the OAuth by inputting the login url on Google IAM.I'm not able to call the functions.

Is there any idea to help me?

Comment: Can you try to add this in the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`? Not sure that is the problem. Else, have a look to this page: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users (Cloud Run and Cloud Functions work similarly on authentication part)

Comment: 1) Are the identities the same for your two examples? 2) What permissions did you grant at the resource (Cloud Functions) for the failing identity? You must add at least "Cloud Functions Invoker". https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating 3) Contrary to the previous comment, Identity Tokens do not have scopes/permissions. The authorization is performed by the resource (Cloud Functions) and not by roles added to the identity.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your answer. I configured my google account as the owner of all system. 
Actually, the "aud" and "azp" embeded in "id_token" are different between two querys, when I decoded "id_token".
What I'm now wondering is  why "id_token" of SDK auth-login is different with "id_token" from Google signin.

Comment: The service account used for the identity does not need any roles unless used or Access tokens also. Do not give it `Owner`. What are the values that are different? Details matter in your case. Also, did you add the email address of the identity to Cloud Functions? Expand your answer with each step you configured.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you so much. You are right. The below steps made me to access Cloud function with http Auth.

[APIS&Services] -> [Credential] -> edit "MY OAuth 2.0 Client ID" -> Set "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" under [Authorized redirect URIs]

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks too. When I set the scope mentioned  on GCP console's IAM, the id_token from google signin is valid for getting the permssion.